# macro to insert hyperlink using Column value

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to create a macro that adds hyperlinks to column A based on value in column A. For example:

```
Column A
1234
2312
4432
```

I want Hyperlink as follows:
"https://fixedstring.com/idno=1234"

Where 1234 is variable based on cell value for that row. and is also the Label.

I want to run this macro against column A for all rows...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
Sub HyperMaker()
   Dim r As Range
   For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      v = r.Value
      If v <> "" Then
         r.Clear
         r.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=r, Address:="https://fixedstring.com/idno=" & v
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```